# Java import not working

Tags: java, import

I'm very new to Java, and this is probably a very dumb question. I'm trying to get a simple input from the user, and to do that I get the `Scanner` class, or `BufferedReader`. Yet when I try to import `java.io.*`, the classes show up undefined.

Here's my code:

```
package testing;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Something {
    public static void logln(String content) {
        System.out.println(content);
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {

    }
    void getInput(String prompt) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner();
    }
}
```

`Scanner s` is showing up undefined. Why might this be?

Comment: The Scanner constructor needs a parameter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner();  // no constructor exists
```

You need to pass a parameter into the Scanner constructor as this class does not have a default no-parameter constructor. You will want to read the error message critically as it will often tell you exactly what is wrong, here that `"The constructor Scanner() is undefined"`.

- If you have similar questions in the future, **always** post the **exact and complete** error message.
- Also, get real friendly with the Java API as it will help you understand the classes that you're using. Here the [Scanner API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) will tell you exactly what constructors are available for this class.

Answer (score 0):

Hovercraft Full Of Eels, has pointed to the correct error.
I would like to add a couple of things -
the correct constructor would be

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Also I don't quite understand why your getter method, getInput() is parametrized. Would you like to elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with java import.

If you want to take input from  inputStream which is typically connected to keyboard input, change your constructor to

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Read the entered input using,

```
String content = sc.nextLine();
```